# Refresh a panel in a user control from parent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to refresh controls of a panel inside a user control from parent control. please help.

Answer (score 3):

you give too little details on what you need to do and why and why is not working right now.

based on your question as it is now, the answer is:

call this code:

```
panel1.Refresh();
```

check here: [Panel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx)

you can edit your question and explain a bit from where you feel you should call or invoke the panel's refresh.